# Best CSS method to specify inter-element spacing (possibly using flexbox, etc.)

Tags: css, spacing, margins

What is the best method in CSS to specify inter-element spacing?

I currently use the following rule to specify a `0.3rem` space between each child of a `.container` element, without adding any space before the first child or after the last child.

```
.container > * + * {
  margin-left:0.3rem;
}
```

Is there a cleaner / more performant way to do this?  I'd imagine that an appropriate CSS property that applied to the `.container` instead of to all-but-one of its children would be more performant, but I haven't yet found such a propery.

Flexbox and/or other more recent CSS improvements are perfectly acceptable.

I'm targeting recent Chrome releases (currently, stable is 28 and dev is 30), but solutions for any browser would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think Flexbox would be used for this purpose?

Comment: I don't think that flexbox will be useful for this, since I couldn't find anything in the W3C flexbox spec that actually does this.  I cited it as an example of newer CSS specs that I'm willing to use.  Before having read the whole flexbox spec, however, I was hopeful that it would have such a CSS property since including it in CSS would be sensible, and flexbox is a much more sensible layout spec than the other CSS / HTML layouts that I've used.

Comment: Is there a problem with what you have already?

Comment: It currently works, but I'd prefer to use a more concise, performant CSS rule if it exists.

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to this question. @XDR, did you find a solution? I like your solution given above, although I did run into problems when ordering the child elements of `.container` using the flexbox `order` property. I'm currently using: `.flex > *:not(:last-child) { margin-right: 97px; }`. I'll post an answer if I find a better solution than what's already been proposed here.

Comment: So, I'm stumped. I've been trying to figure out how to

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try this:

```
.container > .item:first-child{margin-left:0;}
```

Full example:

```css
.clearfix{
 display:table;  
}

.clearfix:after, .clearfix:before{  
 clear:both;  
}

.container{
 background-color:gray;  
}

.container > .item{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:lightblue;

  float:left;
  margin-left: 3em;
}

.container > .item:first-child{
 margin-left:0;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container clearfix">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

Toy can implement it with: **flexbox**, **inline-block** OR **grid system** (float)